# Tycho building bundle generated from jars resulting in Compile error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I created a new plugin from jars in the eclipse IDE. This created a new plugin project containing the classes and all the OSGi stuff: MANIFEST etc.

When Tycho runs, it picks up the project and tries to compile it - and fails. The project contains no source to compile as it contains just the classes from the original jars.

How can I exclude this project from the compile action?

(Just for completeness: the bundle is in Orbit but only a version from 2011. This is why I created my own plugin using the latest version)

Comment: It will only pick the project if and only if you add it as a Maven module ([like here](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/b0f339fa7b9d93474309abb0d4ce0dc0b8949352/pom.xml#L33)). But in your case you should not add it as a Maven module (since it is already compiled), but provide it via a p2 repository (update site).

Comment: I think in similar situations (projects containing only jars or compiled classes but no sources) I have seen failing builds because build.properties contained entries for non-existing "src" directories. But that's just a guess. What exactly is the error message?